# Why is this foreach loop to generate links not working?

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to php and I'm having trouble understanding why this piece of code doesn't work:

```
foreach ($titles as $values) {
 echo '<a href="index.php">' . $values . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Check what $titles has. Use `var_dump($titles);`

Comment: please check variable `$title` must have value

Comment: Your $titles could be null or multi-dimensional. Use var_dump($titles) to inspect the content of $titles. And also enable error display. You may have undefined index titles. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Please show us the error. If the error is not displaying, please enable "display errors" by adding `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the very beginning of your PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$titles=array('title1','title2','title3');
if (is_array($titles)){    
    foreach ($titles as $values) {
     echo '<a href="index.php">' . $values . '</a>';
    } 
}
```

Please check if your $titles is an array first with is_array().

Comment: you cannot assume OP sets her `$titles` variable correctly.

Comment: I modified the answer for this exception.

Comment: still incorrect. This code could lead to more errors. Rather than casting a variable to an array, it's better to check whether it's a valid array using `is_array()` function.